# Counting columns containing data

Tags: sql

I need to be able to count columns that contain data and am not to sure where to start on this. The table is along the lines of:

```
TargetID   Jan   Feb    Mar    Apr   May     Months with data
    1       33   Null    44     32   Null           3
    2      Null   44     32     16    17            4
    3       33    72     Null   Null  14            3
```

I just can't figure out how to create the Months with data column and would appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: Which flavour of SQL are you using?  I'd guess at Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way to do this in SQL is using a `CASE` statement:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when jan is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when feb is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when mar is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when apr is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when may is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as MonthsWithData       
from t;
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any reasonable database.

Note:  Your data structure looks awkward.  In general, you would want to have one row per target and month, with a single column containing the count.  Denormalized data is useful, sometimes, particularly for end-user reports, but in general, it is better to store things the "SQL" way.

Comment: Was going to add my answer - but it's as Gordons note.  I'd create a table with three fields - TargetID, MonthName and MonthValue.  TargetID & MonthName would be a composite primary key so you can't have the same month for the same TargetID more than once.  The SQL would then be `SELECT TargetID, COUNT(MonthValue) FROM Table3 GROUP BY TargetID` or even `SELECT  TargetID, COUNT(MonthName) FROM Table3 WHERE NOT MonthValue IS NULL GROUP BY TargetID`